# Source of highly nucleophilic iodide

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, catalysis, nucleophilicity

What is be the best commercially available source of highly nucleophilic **iodide** in non-polar solvent? Solvents used are cyclohexane, benzene, chlorobenzene.

I can get ahold of bromide quaternary ammonium salts at best. So I'm looking for equal substituent of Bu4NI. Any ideas?

Comment: How about cesium iodide? It's soluble in acetone. But no data for less polar solvents.

Comment: Benzyltributylammonium iodide is pretty good

Comment: @waylander "I can get ahold of bromide quaternary ammonium salts at best".  Is your suggestion commercially available?

Comment: @OscarLanzi  https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/293016?lang=en&region=GB

Comment: A musing, since we had for long a bottle of a solution of 18-crown-6 KCN in the hood only the boss used from time to time, what about the analogue with KI (a bit more than just adding 18-crown-6 + KI + THF, as seen in Acta Cryst 2003, E59,  m1184-m1186 (http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S160053680302676X) Aldrich offers some 18C6 with apolar groups attached, eg. dicyclohexane, or dibenzo, etc.